# Issues building OpenCV with CUDA

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2008

I have CUDA 4.2 and I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.3. My purpose is to work with openCV along with cuda. After downloading I extracted the contents in my C directory and then I generated the openCV solution file by using CMake software. When I am trying to build the solution generated by CMake in Visual studio 2008 then a box getting popped up. In the box there is a message that CMake has regenerated 2 .sln and/or .vcproj files and there are 3 options in the box. One asking to reload the whole solution and issue a new build command, another No to reload the whole solution and stop the build and the last one is the cancel to do nothing. I must mention that though this box is appearing the build is continuing and not stopped, perhaps without generating any error. But getting stuck (without any response) while building row_filter.cu. So when the building gets stuck at this point of time I tried all the options in the box that is appearing, like I reloaded the project and also other options and each time I do anything to reload or even I click cancel I see some kind of error is occurring while re-building the project. So I don't know what to do and how work with openCV and Cuda. Shall I leave the dialogue box just like that or Is there a proper way of building up? I have to start working with OpenCV along with cuda as soon as possible. Thanks fo al your help.

Comment: I think that dialog box is a normal part of the CMake / Visual Studio integration, you generally want to let it reload the solution and project files when it regenerates. If you are concerned about that, close visual studio, re-run CMake, and then reopen the solution and try to build again.

Comment: Yeah, I did that actually.I kept on building the project without re-running the cmake and every time the dialog box is occurring I just kept on clicking the cancel button. In the end it builds successfully without any errors. I will start working with the openCV with cuda and run some sample programs and check out what lies next in my path. Thanks your help.